# Prove the inequality for which a_1>=a_2>=...a_n and b_1>=b_2>=...b_n then

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence

We need to prove: $$( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k)(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k) \le n \sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_k $$

I don't get the hint which is:
$$\sum_{1 \le j \le k \le n} (a_k - a_j)(b_k - b_j)\ge0$$

Which results in
$$ \sum_k a_kb_k\ge \sum_{1 \le j,k \le n} a_kb_j$$

I don't know how to proceed further. Can anyone help me?

Comment: This is Chebyshev's inequality, check here for a proof: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev's_sum_inequality#Proof